# Coalgebra structure on the UEA of a Lie Rinehart algebra

Tags: commutative-algebra

Good evening,

$R$ is a commutative ring and $A$ is a commutative $R$-algebra.
Let $(L,\rho)$ a $(R,A)$-Lie Rinehart algebra. $L$ is a $R$-Lie algebra with a $A$-module structure and $\rho:L\longrightarrow Der_R(A)$ is a morphism of $R$-Lie algebra and of $A$-modules. We have the property
$$[x,ay]=\rho(x)(a)y+a[x,y]$$

I consider $U(L)$ the universal envelopping algebra of $L$. Generaly, $U(L)\otimes_A U(L)$ is not an algebra with the usual rule for tensor product of algebras. i.e: the product
$$(u\otimes v)(u'\otimes v')=uu'\otimes vv'$$
is not defined on $U(L)\otimes_AU(L)$. I don't understand why. I would be gratefull if sommeone can help or give me a reference.

Thank you.